# Extjs property grid

Tags: extjs, propertygrid

I need to display checkbox in extjs property grid for a specific property.  From the api doc, its clear this can be achieved by customEditor property of property grid.

```
My property store: [{name: 'xxx', type: 'boolean', value:'false'},
           {name: 'yyy', type: 'checkbox', value: 'false'}]
```

Here i need to display checkbox for name 'yyy' row. Is this possible to do so?  When i use custom editor like below,

```
Ext.grid.propertyGrid({
  customEditor: {
    'yyy': new Ext.grid.GridEditor(new Ext.form.checkbox())
  }
})
```

the checkbox is displayed in edit mode. But a string(true/false) is displayed in normal mode. I need checkbox to be displayed in normal mode also.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using customRenderers property of propertyGrid as,

```
customRenderers: {
  yyy: function(value) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' name='yyy'>"
  }

}
```

With the above property the checkbox will be displayed in normal mode also.